# jQuery change class on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a site with a floating arrow in the bottom left corner of my site, that shows an arrow pointing down.

Now I want to get the class of the arrow div to change with an arrow pointing up once the the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page.

I am able to get the div class to change once we are near the bottom (at +200px from the bottom, my choice) but the class doesn't change back once the user starts scrolling back to the top.

I have tried toggleClass() but that makes the arrow flicker as the user scrolls up.
I have tried removeClass() and that works well, it removes the class.
And I have tried addClass() but that does nothing.

Could you guys please help me you.

Here is the code snippet :

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 

    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < ($(document).height())-200) {

        $("#floatingArrow").addClass('floatingArrowDown');

    } else if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height())-200) {

        $("#floatingArrow").addClass('floatingArrowUp');

    }
});
```

I've earthed the net, and most of what I have already came from reading articles on the site, but am unable to get this to work.

Thanks

Comment: Try this

`$("#floatingArrow").removeClass( "floatingArrowDown" ).addClass( "floatingArrowUp" );`

Comment: Thanks Syed, this worked great. I don't know if this is the best way to do this but it worked great!!

Comment: I have posted the solution below. please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$("#arrowDV").removeClass( "arrowDown" ).addClass( "arrowUp" );`  I have used an example `mark-up` and this solution worked.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() { 
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < ($(document).height())-200) {
    $("#arrowDV").addClass('arrowDown');
} else if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height())-200) {
$("#arrowDV").removeClass( "arrowDown" ).addClass( "arrowUp" );
}
});
});


.arrowUp
{
background-image: url('url');
height:1000px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: right bottom;
}
.arrowDown
{
background-image: url('url');
height:1000px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: right top;
}

<div id="arrowDV" class="arrowUp"></div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f28fge1e/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

HTML

```
Scroll me down<br><br>
<p>im here</p>
<a href="#" class="scrollup">
<a href="#" class="scrolldown">
```

CSS

```
.scrollup
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 30px;
    display: none;
    background: url( 'Source' ) no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    outline: 0px none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-color: -moz-use-text-color;
}

.scrolldown
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 30px;
    display: none;
    background: url( 'Source' ) no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    outline: 0px none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-color: -moz-use-text-color;
top:20px;
}
```

Jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.scrolldown').fadeIn();
         $(window).scroll(function(){
           if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
           {
                $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
                $('.scrolldown').fadeOut();
            } else {
                $('.scrolldown').fadeIn();
                $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8b7mcbvr/)